# change the name of relations in larvel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

how to change the name of relations in larvel 8?

$query->with('order.linesWithProduct as lines');

get me error "Call to undefined relationship [linesWithProduct as lines] on model [App\Models\Order]"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `with()` doesn't use SQL like that; it's an entirely separate query. If you want your relationship to be named `lines`, you call the function that.

Comment: what does it even mean ?
show us the model relationships and query please.
your question is not descriptive

Comment: can you send the model file with define relation function name

Answer (score -1):

You have to define your relationship  in your model
I suggest to review how to make relationships

Comment: I need the relationship to be called the full name because I have another relationship called lines and lines with a product.
But in the result I want it to be called lines